# After tf.reshape with a tf.tensor as shape input got unknown size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to decode my data and reshape it to the original structure. However, I got unknown shape if I use tf.tensor as input shape. Here is my code

```
def read_tfrecord(example):
feature_description = {
    'df': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'y': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'shape': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'rows': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'columns': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_description)
label = tf.io.decode_raw(example['y'],tf.float64)
shape = tf.io.decode_raw(example['shape'],tf.int64)
df = tf.io.decode_raw(example['df'],tf.float64)
df = tf.reshape(df,shape)
return df,label

def load_dataset(filenames):
    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
        filenames
    ) 
    dataset = dataset.with_options(
        ignore_order
    )
    dataset = dataset.map(
        partial(read_tfrecord), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE
    )
    return dataset

dat = load_dataset('filenames')
```

The tf.data file I read here contains the original shape. When I writing my tf.data file, I got this size by using shape = numpy.asarray(df.shape). It's just something like (A,B). Then after these input pipelines, I rather got my df data with shape (None,None). Is there any reason cause this result? However, if I just manually type the shape as a list value for example (7,11) in tf.reshape part. It will return me this size at the end.

Comment: Can you add a complete traceback of the error?

Comment: @AniketBote Actually there is no error warning comes out from this code. I would expect the shape of this tf data after reshaping will be some number (e.g (3,11)), rather a shape with (None,None).

Comment: Can you add a standalone code to reproduce this issue?